# Images Fall Out of Div When Floated

Tags: html, css

I have many images in this section of my website, and need the to stack into two columns.

I have the widths all correct and the margins, and it looks real nice! However, as soon as I added the `float: left` to the images, some things went wrong.

I have a border at the bottom of each section of content, and the images fall below that border when I float them. I have tried changing the display modes and some other things but I have no clue what is wrong.

[Here is a JSFiddle for my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/SqT5f/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a clearfix on the section that wraps the images. Try Nicolas Gallagher's [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Comment: I'll vote as correct as soon as I can! Thanks man! This is going to be something I can use for more projects as well! It worked great

Comment: No problem, this is a lifesaver for sure

Answer (score 0):

Position the parent of the images (I suggest a div) as relative and add overflow:auto.

CSS file:

```
.content{
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
.data_files{
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="data_files>
        /*here your photos*/
    </div>
</div>
```